# How to use Python to loop through all csv files from a folder on Desktop and input the csv data into dataframe?

Tags: python, csv

I have 3 csv files from a folder named 'C:\Users\name\Downloads\train'.

The 3 csv files are named A, B and C with structure as follows.

senor1, senor2, senor3

x, y, z

I would like to do the following.

1. Create a column 'file_name' in dataframe named df to store the name of csv files (i.e. A, B, C); and
2. Append the data in csv files into the df.

Grateful if someone can suggest me the Python codes for doing such work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest pathlib.
Official doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path(f'C:\\Users\\{name}\\Downloads\\train')    
for filename in list(p.glob('**/*.csv')):
    your code...
```